# Logistic regression gradient descent converge

Tags: regression, logistic, convergence, gradient-descent, likelihood

I have built a logistic regression in python. The Betas are calculated through the gradient descent (ascent actually) method. The change in loglikelihood between iterations is used as a measure to see how close the betas are to their 'true' values.

At what point can it be said that the model has converged? I.e. how small does the change in loglikelihood need to be before one can say that the betas have been found? 1e-10, 1e-100, or 1e-5?

This is important because setting a too small threshold will result in the need for many iterations (i.e. takes much time). Too large a threshold will result in the model being calculated quicker, but less precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have said it yourself: there is a trade-off. So the final answer depends on the costs and benefits you assign for the extra time need to compute versus the potential error.

At the very least you should look at relative change rather than absolute change and you should not choose a cut-off less than the maximum rounding error corresponding to the precision with which the coefficients are stored. The maximum relative rounding error for a number stored in double precision is $2^{-53}\approx10^{-16}$, so that would represent the smallest reasonable cut-off point. You might want to allow for some loss of precision during the computations and choose a somewhat larger number than that.